# Unable to use custom TableViewCell class in UITableViewDelegate Method in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I'm using the latest XCode 6.3 with Swift 1.2. My old code that previously work doesn't work anymore.

I'm trying to use my Custom `UITableViewCell` (`SearchResultsTableViewCell`) in the delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: SearchResultsTableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

but this error message popped up

```
Objective-C method 'tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:' provided by method 'tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)' in protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'
```

Help please. Thanks

Comment: I ma using this and its working fine. func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {...}

Comment: I am using a custom cell which i put into the parameter (SearchResultsTableViewCell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of putting the cell there. It will work fine with `UITableViewCell`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//code

}
```

If you want to access you can typecast the UITableViewCell to your desired custom cell.

Answer (score 3):

Declare cell as UITableViewCell and downcast it to SearchResultsTableViewCell.

```
func
tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let aSearchResultsTableViewCell = cell as! SearchResultsTableViewCell

}
```